# error in connecting to a smtp server with python

Tags: python, email, smtp

import smtplib

SERVER = "my.smtp.server.com"

FROM = "myemail@somehost.ca"
TO = ["someemail@somehost.mun.ca"] # must be a list

SUBJECT = "Hello!"

TEXT = "hello"

Here is my code:

```
# Prepare actual message

message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.login('loginname','password')
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\New Text Document.py", line 24, in ?
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\smtplib.py", line 241, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\smtplib.py", line 289, in connect
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: (11001, 'getaddrinfo failed')
```

what do I do next?

Comment: Does a `host my.smtp.server.com` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ip for `my.smtp.server.com` in your **dns** or **/etc/hosts** ?

-> [DNS Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)

is `my.smtp.server.com` a real (smtp-)server ?

have tried a telnet to port 25 of `my.smtp.server.com` ?

firewall problems ?

if you need a test-server -> [lamson](http://lamsonproject.org/)

Comment: my.smtp.server.com was just a place holder. anyways It was just a simple typo... as is the cause of many scripting errors. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your dns is not working. Perhaps my.smtp.server.com is a placeholder, if so substitute the real mail server name in there

Answer (score 0):

First check by setting debug level to true,
        server = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
        server.set_debuglevel(1)

Check if the server is using a SSL protocol or TLS,
for SSL with SMTP, you will have to call this function,(if you are using SES, this is the function you should be calling)
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)

If the SMTP server is using tls, starttls with the function below
        server = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()

Answer (score 0):

Check this website to ensure you have the correct hostname and port addresses for smtplib

```
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040
```